# Twilio API not receiving well formed XML after upgrading from 4.x to 5.4.1

Tags: c#, xml, twilio, twilio-api

I'm in the process of upgrading our Twilio integration from 4.x to 5.x and in testing, I've found that some of our features aren't working. Dialing from the page seems to have broken and the Twilio Console is spitting out this error:

WARNING 12200 Schema validation warning

DESCRIPTION Cannot find the declaration of element 'string'.

The Twilio Console says Twilio is receiving the following:

```
<string
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt; &lt;Response&gt; &lt;Dial callerId="8177683849"&gt;7703095317&lt;/Dial&gt;&lt;/Response&gt;
```

When I debug into my code, I'm sending XML from a string value twilioMsg.ResponseWrite whose value is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Response><Dial callerId="8177683849">7703095317</Dial></Response>
```

I'm creating the Twilio call in our application code like this:

```
var num = new PhoneNumber(request.LeadNumber);
var response = new VoiceResponse();
response.Dial(num.ToString(), callerId: request.CallerId);
twilioMsg.ResponseWrite = response.ToString();
twilioMsg.SetResponse();

Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, twilioMsg.ResponseWrite, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
```

I'm not sure why the ResponseWrite string value is encoding the ">" and "<" as the lt; and gt; characters, which I assume is what's causing the issue. Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: I'm not sure what some of your objects are but my guess would be to remove the `ToString()` from `response.ToString()`

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm trying to show the least amount of non-relevant code possible. I've edited to show what it is. It's Twilio's VoiceResponse object.

Comment: What if you remove `new System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter()` from `CreateResponse()`? As you said, something is XML encoding your output that is already in the correct format.

Comment: Remove the xml identification : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>.  It looks like it is causing issues with the Twilio.

Comment: HI, are you using WebApi for this? Seems like your XML is getting encoded. Can you confirm?